# css align horizontally + vertically 3 elements wihin a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set my own distances inside a div for a sequence of 3 elements:

1) a checkbox
2) an image
3) a text

I would like:

> 1)the checkbox to be 1 pixel distant from the left border of the
>   containing div  + aligned vertically in the middle
>
> 2)the image to be 1 pixel distant from the checkbox                + aligned
>   vertically in the middle
>
> 3)the text to be 1 pixel distant from the image                + aligned
>   vertically in the middle

If I use vertical-align middle it aligns perfectly the elements but it doesn't let me space them horizontally!

I also found good solutions for IE or for FF, but I cannot find 1 solution that does the job for all the browsers!

You can see the full code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/WNeLW/

Comment: See my answer if i am lagging some where let me know so i can understand your requirement better.

Comment: Dear check my updated fiddle... and let me know if still any issues you are facing.. so i can work on it and solve your problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle it might help you. If i am not getting you problem then this will be helpful.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WNeLW/1/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WNeLW/1/embedded/result/

Updated Code Tested in IE6:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WNeLW/10/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WNeLW/10/embedded/result/

Comment: Unfortunately it works with FF and Chrome, but not in IE 7 and lower which shows a completely messed up layout!